# What is the difference between a quadrivector and a 4-vector?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, metric-tensor, vectors, definition

What is the difference between a [quadrivector](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadrivector) and a [4-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector)?

Why is the square of a 4-vector equal to $t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$ while the square of a quadrivector is equal to $t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$? Aren't they the same mathematical object?

EDIT : Ok I actually understand that the above calculations depend of the metric, so my question changes : Why are the temporal elements of the Minkowski metric (or, more generaly, any metric involving time) of opposite sign compared to spatial elements ?

Comment: Where are you getting this from? Both depend on the metric, in general.

Comment: @FGSUZ It's more than just sign conventions; the 4-vector square in this question is computed using the Euclidean metric, and the quadrivector square in this question is computed using a Minkowski metric.

Comment: Oops, I accidentaly read a minus sign in front of the first expression. Sorry.

Comment: Quadri- and 4- are the same thing

Comment: I'm asking because i know the square of a conventional vector is the quadratic sum of its elements. But when i learned and proved special relativity at university (2 years ago), we proved that the square of a quadrivector is the one in my question. I'll learn about metrics (i don't know what it is). But it looks awkards that 2 identical objects don't act equaly.

Comment: "Quadrivector" is a nonstandard term. Whatever source you're looking at actually appears to be using "quadrivector" to mean what people normally refer to as a four-vector. Please tell us whose terminology this is, and give us a reference to what set of definitions they're using.

Comment: The clarified version of this question is a duplicate of [Why does time in Minkowski's space have the opposite sign of the space coordinates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283674/106502)

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. The square of a four vector (in inertial coordinates) is either $c^2 t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$ or $-c^2 t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$ depending on the signature of the metric. Quadrivector is not a term I am familiar with, but with that definition it looks like it is just another name for a four vector.

Comment: Ok I learned that what we call quadrivector (in French... so sorry if the word is not used in english) is simply a 4-vector in a Minkowski space.

So my question changes (I edit it) : Why are the temporal elements of the Minkowski metric (or, more generaly, any metric involving time) of opposite sign compared to spatial elements ?

Thanks.