# Proper time and its definition

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

Why is proper time defined to be of opposite sign of the space time interval ds? Shouldnt it be exactly the space time interval?

My question was not about time having opposite sign it was about proper time for which I thought is the same as space time interval in the rest frame..but I realized that its not.

Comment: That is a matter of conventions, starting with your preferred Minkowski signature convention.

Comment: The sign relationship between  $s^2$ and $\tau^2$ is entirely an artifact of way you choose to define your scalar product. If you chose the right metric (that is the one used by particle physicists) they have the same same.

Comment: But why? If you are in a rest frame space part goes to zero and you are left with just the time part...why o why would you now set it to a opposite sign?

Comment: aaaaaa......if you have ds2=-c2dt2 then you can take the dt2 and have it without that sign? Why then is there a book which says that relation is strictly with the opposite sign when it is actually a matter of convention? Just realized...con -with venio in letin -to go. So convention...going with (the flow:) )....

Comment: Using the (-+++) metric makes the spacial part of the inner product the same as the one familiar from earlier work, for one thing. Basically, whatever choice you make is going to require grappling with something new and awkward. Different people chose different kinds of awkward. FSM forfend but some people write their Lorentz vectors with a $i$ in the time-like component (that is $(ict,x,y,z)$ of all things) to avoid the sign issues.

Comment: BTW-- We have MathJax running on the size so you can write proper path. Write `\tau^2` inside of dollar signs and it come out $\tau^2$.

Comment: Yeah i know but i dont know how to use it.. Thanks for the tip.. Now i know a little bit. But not enough. And you have it running on the site not size :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does time in Minkowski's space have the opposite sign of the space coordinates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283674/)

Comment: No, its not a duplicate, at least not judging by the title of the question. I know why that is so...my confusion was about proper time being equal to the space time interval...which it is not. In space time geometry metric is such that interval has a certain signature...that is, metric does. I just thought that in the rest frame, proper time and spacew time interval are the same thing. A moment of confusion...I just realized...con- with fusio - to fuse.....to melt together...