# Why is the time coordinate different in the metric?

Tags: metric-tensor, metric-space

I have been using the metric for quite a while now and I never thought about it. Why does the time coordinate always have an opposite sign to the space one?

In other words, why does the metric have this form(in free space)?
$$
ds^2= -dt^2+d\vec{x}^2
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does time in Minkowski's space have the opposite sign of the space coordinates?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283674/why-does-time-in-minkowskis-space-have-the-opposite-sign-of-the-space-coordinat)

Comment: Not really, I'm interested in what the sign means rather than if it works.

Comment: A kind of interpretation answer may be the following. The difference between time and space is the fact that you can only go in one direction in time: forward. This is precisely what happens (in a Black Hole metric) when you cross an event horizon. there is a kind of sign flip, from your perspective, and the singularity cannot be avoided in the same way you cannot avoid 9am tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is because the universality of the speed of light requires it.  The detailed reasoning is in the derivation of the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: So what does the Lorentz transformation really mean in that case?

Comment: The web has a wealth of learning material on what the metric means, and how the Lorentz transformation describes the detailed features of Special  Relativity that make all observers see the same speed of light.  Only you can choose the material appropriate to your own current level of understanding.